# Applying patch does not create files with "add" status

Tags: svn, versioning, patch

I typically work on large chunks of code on a project, and from time to time have to back up my data to patches:

```
svn diff > /backups/assignment-XX_diff-YY.patch
```

I then revert-and-update my local working copy:

```
svn revert -R . && svn up
```

I then go to work on my other assignment, and when it is committed, I clean up and revert locally, then re-apply my patch from the work I was doing earlier:

```
svn revert -R .
svn up
patch -p0 < /backups/assignment-XX_diff-YY.patch
```

One thing I have noticed is that when I have created a new file, then add the file, e.g.:

```
touch newFile.cpp
svn add newFile.cpp
```

Newly added files and their contents are in the patch I create, and the files are recreated when I apply the patch, but the "added" status is not automatically set when I apply the patch. This has resulted in my applying a patch that is ready to commit, but only the "modified" files get committed, not the "added" files. Also, the "new" files, if they were already present, now have the entire patch appended to the EOF, breaking them.

So, in summary: Is it possible to have `patch` automatically issue the `svn add` command on new/added files when it applies a patch to my local working copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with svn 1.7 new command `svn patch`.

Run `svn patch /backups/assignment-XX_diff-YY.patch` instead of `patch -p0 < /backups/assignment-XX_diff-YY.patch`. From [Apache Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#patch):

> svn patch will apply unidiff changes to existing files just like third
>   party patch tools. It will also add newly created files to version
>   control, and delete files and directories which are left empty after
>   patching.

Comment: version 1.9.5 svn patch skips files not found.. not adding new files from patch. This seems like a bug.

Comment: @kchoi, yes it is a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4525.

Comment: @kchoi I also got this situation with SVN 1.9.7 but in my case, the added files had been locally added as unversioned already. After removing them, the patch has been applied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

To include newly added files in patch, we can use the --show-copies-as-adds option

svn diff --show-copies-as-adds > TARGET_PATCH_FILE